# Preposition To after a noun

Tags: prepositions

Today I read in Wall Street Hournal next title:

> Wells Fargo **to** Pay States About $575 Million to Settle Customer Harm
>   Claims

Why do they use “to” after Wells Fargo? Was there omitted something?

Comment: "to" is an infinitive marker here, not a preposition. "To" when used in headlines is comparable to "will", that is, it refers to a future event.

Comment: @user178049 Thus, can we omit “to” or it’s a strict rule?

Comment: It's not really a rule. It's just a writing style, called [headlinese](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese). You don't omit "to", but you can replace it with "will".

Comment: ... the verb "be" is ellipted. In full it would be "Wells Fargo **Are** to Pay States About $575 Million to Settle Customer Harm Claims